# has_one any different than has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :name, :unit, :description, :stock, :limit
  has_many :cart_rows
  has_one :inquery
end
```

and

```
class Inquery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product, :text, :phone, :zip, :product_id, :state, :street, :city
  belongs_to :product
end
```

In my index of Inqueries view I have:

```
<% @inqueries.each do |inquery| %>
  <%= inquery.product.name %>
  <%= inquery.text %>
<% end %>
```

And I get the following error: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

What am I doing wrong? Does `has_one` behave differently than `has_many`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built an app based on the info you described here, and was able to reproduce your problem by having an Inquery record with nil values for product (also for text).  You may wish to add better validators so that Inqueries with nils cannot be saved.

Here's a paste from my rails console session:

```
  Inquery Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "inqueries".* FROM "inqueries" 
#<Inquery:0x00000002c03e40>
 => [#<Inquery id: 1, text: nil, phone: nil, zip: nil, product_id: nil, state: nil, street: nil, city: nil, created_at: "2012-08-17 15:23:49", updated_at: "2012-08-17 15:23:49">] 

1.9.3p194 :002 > Inquery.all.each { |n| puts n.product.name }
  Inquery Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "inqueries".* FROM "inqueries" 
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

As an aside, and now for some unsolicited advice: a field with the same name as a keyword, "text", is a really bad idea.  You might not shoot yourself in the foot today, but you will at some point.  Consider renaming the text field to usertext or description or something like that.

Comment: Technically :text and not text is, but it's just confusing to use a type as a variable name whether we're talking about 'text' or 'string' or 'integer'.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

Comment: Well, it's not really a keyword, it just happens to be one of the option for a column type... Anyways, I agree that he could have chosen  a more descriptive name like description. But other than that, I dont think it will cause any problems.

Comment: This is awesome! JD, you're right. I had some older data in the DB. Also, I appreciate unsolicited advice. Will make the change!

Answer (score 2):

No, you should be able to call `inquery.product`. You probably have an inquery with no product.

In the console (`rails c`), run: `Inquery.where(product_id: nil)`, and see if you get results.

You should validate the presence of the product, in the Inquery model:

```
validates :product, presence: true
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an Inquery that does not have a product attached.

When you call `inquery.product` you are returning a nil value, and when you then call `.name` on the nil value, you are getting the error. This has nothing to do with has_one or has_many